# Binary Search Tree, Height Method not returning correct values

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Java Binary Search trees, Height method not returning the correct height. I tried a lot of stuff on the internet, none of it worked. If someone can point out the issue with my code it will be very helpful.

```
@Override
public int height()
{
    
    return heightRecursive(root);
        
}
    
private int heightRecursive(Node node) {
        
    if(node == null || (node.right == null && node.right == null)) return 0;
        
    int lh=0;
    int rh=0;
            
    if(node.left!=null) {
        lh=heightRecursive(node.left);
        System.out.println(lh);
    }
    if(node.right!=null) {
        rh=heightRecursive(node.right);
    }
        
    //System.out.println("--------"+1+Math.max(lh, rh));
        
    return 1+Math.max(lh, rh);
            
}
```

The Add() Method is below:

```
@Override
public boolean add(Comparable e)
{
    addR(e,root);
    return true;
}
public Node addR(Comparable e,Node n) 
{
    //System.out.println("Null --"+n+" "+e+" "+size);
    if(n==null)
    {
            
        n=new Node(e);
        size++;
        System.out.println("final --"+n+" "+e+" "+size);
            
    }
        
    else if(e.compareTo(n.value)<0)
    {
            
        n.left = addR(e,n.left);
        //size++;
    }
    else if(e.compareTo(n.value)>0) 
    {
        n.right = addR(e,n.right);
        //size++;
    }

    return n;
}
```

I can't seem to get to the root cause of this, after inputting the debug printline code in add method, this is the output:

```
A final --trees.SimpleTreeSet$Node@58c1670b A 1
B final --trees.SimpleTreeSet$Node@6b57696f B 2
R final --trees.SimpleTreeSet$Node@44c8afef R 1
W final --trees.SimpleTreeSet$Node@12f41634 W 1
O final --trees.SimpleTreeSet$Node@262b2c86 O 1
final --trees.SimpleTreeSet$Node@5ed828d A 1
Y final --trees.SimpleTreeSet$Node@7a3d45bd Y 1
```

Comment: The name of the language is Java, not "JAVA."

Comment: In order to reproduce what you are getting please provide all your code and input as well.

Comment: Your `addR` method will simply fail to add a node that has a value equal to that of an existing node. I don't know if that is intentional. It is also unclear from the code shown how the root node is ever set, since `add` ignores the return value from `addR`, or where the `size` variable is declared.

Comment: Your output also doesn't make any sense. The only uncommented println call you show us in your code would only produce lines beginning with "final," never anything like "A final". It seems the code in your question is different from the code you are running.

Comment: If you were to uncomment `System.out.println("--------"+1+Math.max(lh, rh));` it would print the wrong value. If `Math.max(lh, rh)` were `7`, it would print `"--------17"`. You need parentheses around the arithmetic subexpression.

Comment: In line, `if(node == null || (node.right == null && node.right == null)) return 0;`, one of those nodes ought to be node.left.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in your `add` method: the `root` will never change. So if you add a first node to an empty tree, that new node is lost: it is returned by `addR`, but your code ignores it.

So:

```
public boolean add(Comparable e)
{
    root = addR(e,root);
    return true;
}
```

Another problem concerns the base case of the height recursion:

```
if(node == null || (node.right == null && node.right == null)) return 0;
```

You should check `node.left` (not twice `node.right`) and also distinguish between a `null` and a node. There is a height difference between those two cases. When a single-node-tree has height 0, then an empty tree should have height -1.

Corrected:

```
if (node == null) return -1;
if (node.left == null && node.right == null)) return 0;
```